# How to Notify Window of Right Click Event in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am currently trying to programmatically trigger a right-click notify event from a TreeViewControl to my main window, but apparently the message does not trigger the message handler in the respective view.

To trigger the message I use the following code:

```cpp
CWnd* mainwindow = AfxGetMainWnd();
NMHDR hdr;
hdr.hwndFrom = mainwindow->GetSafeHwnd();
hdr.idFrom = IDC_TREEVIEW;
hdr.code = NM_RCLICK;
mainwindow->SendMessage(WM_NOTIFY, (WPARAM)IDC_TREEVIEW, (LPARAM)&hdr);
```

The view implements the following message map:

```cpp
IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CMainView, CFormView)

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainView, CFormView)
    ON_NOTIFY(NM_RCLICK, IDC_TREEVIEW, OnRightClick)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


void CMainView::OnRightClick(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult) {
/* ... */
}
```

I never seem to run into the `OnRightClick()`-function even though the message is sent. What am I missing here?

Comment: `AfxGetMainWnd()` is the main (frame) window. You send the notification there, but the list-control's parent is not that, it's the `CMainView` instance. Try sending the notification to the view instead (`AfxGetMainWnd()->GetActiveView()`). If your app is MDI you will have to go through the child-frame. You may need to use some typecasts too. And I'm not sure if `hdr.hwndFrom` must be the main window or the control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [Constantine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76713948/how-to-notify-window-of-right-click-event-in-mfc?noredirect=1#comment135249970_76713948) the solution was to change `hdr.hwndFrom` to refer to the handle of the `IDC_TREEVIEW` control instead of the main window's handle.

With that in place the message was evaluated properly and the code ran in the respective Handler.